# Do scrapy Rules apply to redirects

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have instantiated the following crawl spider:

```
from .other_rules import default_rules

class MyProjectSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_spider'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.allowed_domains = [kwargs.get('domain')]
        self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_link')]
        aditional_rules = kwargs.get('rules')

        if aditional_rules!=None:
            aditional_rules = aditional_rules.split(', ')
            rules = tuple(default_rules + aditional_rules)
        else:
            rules = tuple(default_rules)

        self.rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=rules), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        )
        super(MyProjectSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My goal is to remove all links which include certain symbols ('?','&'...), as well as links to language pages which are not English. I made a list in another file, and imported it. So, the first couple of rules look something like this:

```
default_rules = [
        r'[\S]{0,}/[0-9]{1,5}/[\S]{0,}',
        r'[\S]{0,}[?]{1,}[\S]{0,}',
        r'[\S]{0,}[&]{1,}[\S]{0,}',
        r'[\S]{0,}[=]{1,}[\S]{0,}',
        r'[\S]{0,}/abkhazian/[\S]{0,}',
        r'[\S]{0,}/ab/[\S]{0,}',
        r'[\S]{0,}/afar/[\S]{0,}',
        r'[\S]{0,}/aa/[\S]{0,}',
        ...

]
```

I tested this script, and it works fine for the languages. However, often I catch that the rules regarding symbols have not been fully implemented. For example, when I try Yahoo news, the script does not catch urls like this:
https://sports.yahoo.com/college-womens-basketball/?_guc_consent_skip=1543573861/

I've tested these regex expressions in a Python shell, and they work just fine. Is it possible that the rules are not implemented in case of redirects? This is my best guess so far, but I haven't been able to confirm it. Or is there maybe another issue in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link extractor of your rule is only used to extract links from the parsed pages.
It has no function beyond that, so it will not affect redirects.

If you want to control which redirects are followed, you'll probably need a custom redirect middleware.
Modifying the built-in [`RedirectMiddleware`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect) to suit your needs shouldn't be too complicated.

As a side-note, rules work with partial matches.
This means every instance of `[\S]{0,}` (better written `\S*`) can be left out.
It also means your `default_rules` list can be simplified to:

```
default_rules = [
    r'/\d{1,5}/',
    r'\?',
    r'&',
    r'=',
    r'/abkhazian/',
    r'/ab/',
    r'/afar/',
    r'/aa/',
    ...

]
```